# AWS Amplify Access Is Denied After Deleting Cognito User Pool

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, aws-cli

**EDIT**

when I look at the @aws-amplify/cli folder in my node_modules, I can see there is an error with the tsconfig.json file but I can't see what the error is. Here is the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": ["*.ts", "package.json"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

**END EDIT**

I have a NextJS app hosted on AWS Amplify and I successfully deployed the Amplify Authentication to my app. Then I noticed there was an issue with the Sign Up screen (not displaying the required attributes fields) so I deleted my Cognito user pools to redeploy Auth but now when I come to deploy the Auth again using `amplify pull --appId xxxxxxxxx --envName xxxx`, I am continually getting "Access is denied" errors. No matter which amplify command I try, I still get the same error (see screenshot). How can I fix this?[image]